# Display last date a post was updated on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using some PHP to display the last time a blog post was updated on WordPress using the `get_the_time` and `get_the_modified_time` functions. However, I can't get the last modified time to display inline in the paragraph.

```
 <?php 
        $x = get_the_time('U');             
        $m = get_the_modified_time('U');    
        if ($m != $x) { 
            $t = the_modified_time('F d, Y');
            echo "<p class=\"lastupdated\">Updated on $t </p>"; 
        } 
    ?>
```

Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`the_modified_time`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_time) *prints* the last modification time, so it prints it before you print your `<p>`.

Instead you'll want to use `get_the_modified_time` for setting `$t`, like so:

```
$t = get_the_modified_time('F d, Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because these functions don't return the result but `echo` it directly. Thus you must call them at the spot you need them to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php 
            $x = get_the_time('U');             
            $m = get_the_modified_time('U');    
            if ($m != $x) { 
                echo "<p class=\"lastupdated\">Updated on ".the_modified_time('F d, Y')."</p>"; 
            } 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also display the last modified time of a post through this code by placing it anywhere in your loop.

```
Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
<?php $u_time = get_the_time('U');
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');
if($u_modified_time != $u_time) {
    echo "and last modified on ";
    the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
    echo ". ";
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete code based on the above comments. Now it works and you just need to add this to your post template:
 **Snippet (1)**

```
<?php 
        $x = get_the_time('U');             
        $m = get_the_modified_time('U');    
        if ($m != $x) { 
            $t = get_the_modified_time('F d, Y');
            echo "<p class=\"lastupdated\">Updated on $t </p>"; 
        } 
    ?>
```

For example, suppose that your post template is called `content-post.php`. Look for a part that looks like the below:
 **Snippet (2)**

```
            // Post date
            if ( in_array( 'post-date', $post_meta_top ) ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></a>
            <?php endif;
```

Insert snippet **(2)** immediately before the closing tag of snippet **(1)** as follows:

```
        <?php

        // Post date
        if ( in_array( 'post-date', $post_meta_top ) ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></a>

        <?php 
            $x = get_the_time('U');             
        $m = get_the_modified_time('U');    
        if ($m != $x) { 
        $t = get_the_modified_time('F d, Y');
        echo "<p class=\"lastupdated\">Updated on $t </p>"; 
            } 
            ?>


        <?php endif;
```

Now, you will get the original post date and the updated post date. Special thanks go to @Sebastian Paaske Tørholm for his comment.